# PowerMock and javassist conflict

Tags: maven, junit4, powermock, javassist

I have faced with a problem that when I am trying to run my unit tests on this versions:

```
PowerMock - 1.6.5

javaassist - 3.12.1.GA

java8
```

I am getting this:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to transform class with name com.energyict.ems.mstr.MstrSessionManager. Reason: java.io.IOException: invalid constant type: 15

    at org.powermock.core.classloader.MockClassLoader.loadMockClass(MockClassLoader.java:283)
    at org.powermock.core.classloader.MockClassLoader.loadModifiedClass(MockClassLoader.java:192)
    at org.powermock.core.classloader.DeferSupportingClassLoader.loadClass(DeferSupportingClassLoader.java:71)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:348)
    at sun.reflect.generics.factory.CoreReflectionFactory.makeNamedType(CoreReflectionFactory.java:114)
    at sun.reflect.generics.visitor.Reifier.visitClassTypeSignature(Reifier.java:125)
    at sun.reflect.generics.tree.ClassTypeSignature.accept(ClassTypeSignature.java:49)
    at sun.reflect.annotation.AnnotationParser.parseSig(AnnotationParser.java:439)
    at sun.reflect.annotation.AnnotationParser.parseClassValue(AnnotationParser.java:420)
    at sun.reflect.annotation.AnnotationParser.parseClassArray(AnnotationParser.java:724)
    at sun.reflect.annotation.AnnotationParser.parseArray(AnnotationParser.java:531)
    at sun.reflect.annotation.AnnotationParser.parseMemberValue(AnnotationParser.java:355)
    at sun.reflect.annotation.AnnotationParser.parseAnnotation2(AnnotationParser.java:286)
    at sun.reflect.annotation.AnnotationParser.parseAnnotations2(AnnotationParser.java:120)
    at sun.reflect.annotation.AnnotationParser.parseAnnotations(AnnotationParser.java:72)
    at java.lang.Class.createAnnotationData(Class.java:3521)
    at java.lang.Class.annotationData(Class.java:3510)
    at java.lang.Class.getAnnotation(Class.java:3415)
    at org.junit.internal.MethodSorter.getDeclaredMethods(MethodSorter.java:52)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.TestClass.getAnnotatedMethods(TestClass.java:45)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.MethodValidator.validateTestMethods(MethodValidator.java:71)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.MethodValidator.validateStaticMethods(MethodValidator.java:44)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.MethodValidator.validateMethodsForDefaultRunner(MethodValidator.java:50)
    at org.powermock.modules.junit4.internal.impl.PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl.validate(PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl.java:108)
    at org.powermock.modules.junit4.internal.impl.PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl.<init>(PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl.java:70)
    at org.powermock.modules.junit4.internal.impl.PowerMockJUnit47RunnerDelegateImpl.<init>(PowerMockJUnit47RunnerDelegateImpl.java:42)
    at org.powermock.modules.junit4.internal.impl.PowerMockJUnit49RunnerDelegateImpl.<init>(PowerMockJUnit49RunnerDelegateImpl.java:25)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
    at org.powermock.modules.junit4.common.internal.impl.JUnit4TestSuiteChunkerImpl.createDelegatorFromClassloader(JUnit4TestSuiteChunkerImpl.java:172)
    at org.powermock.modules.junit4.common.internal.impl.JUnit4TestSuiteChunkerImpl.createDelegatorFromClassloader(JUnit4TestSuiteChunkerImpl.java:48)
    at org.powermock.tests.utils.impl.AbstractTestSuiteChunkerImpl.createTestDelegators(AbstractTestSuiteChunkerImpl.java:113)
    at org.powermock.modules.junit4.common.internal.impl.JUnit4TestSuiteChunkerImpl.<init>(JUnit4TestSuiteChunkerImpl.java:71)
    at org.powermock.modules.junit4.common.internal.impl.AbstractCommonPowerMockRunner.<init>(AbstractCommonPowerMockRunner.java:32)
    at org.powermock.modules.junit4.PowerMockRunner.<init>(PowerMockRunner.java:34)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
    at org.junit.internal.builders.AnnotatedBuilder.buildRunner(AnnotatedBuilder.java:29)
    at org.junit.internal.builders.AnnotatedBuilder.runnerForClass(AnnotatedBuilder.java:21)
    at org.junit.runners.model.RunnerBuilder.safeRunnerForClass(RunnerBuilder.java:59)
    at org.junit.internal.builders.AllDefaultPossibilitiesBuilder.runnerForClass(AllDefaultPossibilitiesBuilder.java:26)
    at org.junit.runners.model.RunnerBuilder.safeRunnerForClass(RunnerBuilder.java:59)
    at org.junit.internal.requests.ClassRequest.getRunner(ClassRequest.java:26)
    at com.intellij.junit4.JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.java:49)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.IdeaTestRunner$Repeater.startRunnerWithArgs(IdeaTestRunner.java:51)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:237)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:70)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:147)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.io.IOException: invalid constant type: 15
    at javassist.CtClassType.getClassFile2(CtClassType.java:203)
    at javassist.CtClassType.subtypeOf(CtClassType.java:303)
    at javassist.CtClassType.subtypeOf(CtClassType.java:318)
    at javassist.compiler.MemberResolver.compareSignature(MemberResolver.java:247)
    at javassist.compiler.MemberResolver.lookupMethod(MemberResolver.java:119)
    at javassist.compiler.MemberResolver.lookupMethod(MemberResolver.java:96)
    at javassist.compiler.TypeChecker.atMethodCallCore(TypeChecker.java:704)
    at javassist.expr.NewExpr$ProceedForNew.setReturnType(NewExpr.java:243)
    at javassist.compiler.JvstTypeChecker.atCallExpr(JvstTypeChecker.java:146)
    at javassist.compiler.ast.CallExpr.accept(CallExpr.java:45)
    at javassist.compiler.TypeChecker.atVariableAssign(TypeChecker.java:248)
    at javassist.compiler.TypeChecker.atAssignExpr(TypeChecker.java:217)
    at javassist.compiler.ast.AssignExpr.accept(AssignExpr.java:38)
    at javassist.compiler.CodeGen.doTypeCheck(CodeGen.java:241)
    at javassist.compiler.CodeGen.atStmnt(CodeGen.java:329)
    at javassist.compiler.ast.Stmnt.accept(Stmnt.java:49)
    at javassist.compiler.CodeGen.atStmnt(CodeGen.java:350)
    at javassist.compiler.ast.Stmnt.accept(Stmnt.java:49)
    at javassist.compiler.CodeGen.atIfStmnt(CodeGen.java:404)
    at javassist.compiler.CodeGen.atStmnt(CodeGen.java:354)
    at javassist.compiler.ast.Stmnt.accept(Stmnt.java:49)
    at javassist.compiler.Javac.compileStmnt(Javac.java:568)
    at javassist.expr.NewExpr.replace(NewExpr.java:206)
    at org.powermock.core.transformers.impl.AbstractMainMockTransformer$PowerMockExpressionEditor.edit(AbstractMainMockTransformer.java:436)
    at javassist.expr.ExprEditor.loopBody(ExprEditor.java:211)
    at javassist.expr.ExprEditor.doit(ExprEditor.java:90)
    at javassist.CtClassType.instrument(CtClassType.java:1374)
    at org.powermock.core.transformers.impl.ClassMockTransformer.transformMockClass(ClassMockTransformer.java:65)
    at org.powermock.core.transformers.impl.AbstractMainMockTransformer.transform(AbstractMainMockTransformer.java:247)
    at org.powermock.core.classloader.MockClassLoader.loadMockClass(MockClassLoader.java:264)
    ... 57 more
Caused by: java.io.IOException: invalid constant type: 15
    at javassist.bytecode.ConstPool.readOne(ConstPool.java:1090)
    at javassist.bytecode.ConstPool.read(ConstPool.java:1033)
    at javassist.bytecode.ConstPool.<init>(ConstPool.java:149)
    at javassist.bytecode.ClassFile.read(ClassFile.java:737)
    at javassist.bytecode.ClassFile.<init>(ClassFile.java:108)
    at javassist.CtClassType.getClassFile2(CtClassType.java:190)
    ... 86 more
```

But when I am trying to change javaassist version on, for example: 3.20.0-GA

```
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.javassist</groupId>
            <artifactId>javassist</artifactId>
            <version>3.20.0-GA</version>
        </dependency>
```

I am getting next error:

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: javassist.CtMethod.hasAnnotation(Ljava/lang/Class;)Z

    at org.powermock.core.transformers.impl.TestClassTransformer.removeTestAnnotationsForTestMethodsThatRunOnOtherClassLoader(TestClassTransformer.java:189)
    at org.powermock.core.transformers.impl.TestClassTransformer.transform(TestClassTransformer.java:203)
    at org.powermock.core.classloader.MockClassLoader.loadMockClass(MockClassLoader.java:264)
    at org.powermock.core.classloader.MockClassLoader.loadModifiedClass(MockClassLoader.java:192)
    at org.powermock.core.classloader.DeferSupportingClassLoader.loadClass(DeferSupportingClassLoader.java:71)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:348)
    at org.powermock.modules.junit4.common.internal.impl.JUnit4TestSuiteChunkerImpl.createDelegatorFromClassloader(JUnit4TestSuiteChunkerImpl.java:161)
    at org.powermock.modules.junit4.common.internal.impl.JUnit4TestSuiteChunkerImpl.createDelegatorFromClassloader(JUnit4TestSuiteChunkerImpl.java:48)
    at org.powermock.tests.utils.impl.AbstractTestSuiteChunkerImpl.createTestDelegators(AbstractTestSuiteChunkerImpl.java:113)
    at org.powermock.modules.junit4.common.internal.impl.JUnit4TestSuiteChunkerImpl.<init>(JUnit4TestSuiteChunkerImpl.java:71)
    at org.powermock.modules.junit4.common.internal.impl.AbstractCommonPowerMockRunner.<init>(AbstractCommonPowerMockRunner.java:32)
    at org.powermock.modules.junit4.PowerMockRunner.<init>(PowerMockRunner.java:34)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
    at org.junit.internal.builders.AnnotatedBuilder.buildRunner(AnnotatedBuilder.java:29)
    at org.junit.internal.builders.AnnotatedBuilder.runnerForClass(AnnotatedBuilder.java:21)
    at org.junit.runners.model.RunnerBuilder.safeRunnerForClass(RunnerBuilder.java:59)
    at org.junit.internal.builders.AllDefaultPossibilitiesBuilder.runnerForClass(AllDefaultPossibilitiesBuilder.java:26)
    at org.junit.runners.model.RunnerBuilder.safeRunnerForClass(RunnerBuilder.java:59)
    at org.junit.internal.requests.ClassRequest.getRunner(ClassRequest.java:26)
    at com.intellij.junit4.JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.java:49)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.IdeaTestRunner$Repeater.startRunnerWithArgs(IdeaTestRunner.java:51)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:237)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:70)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:147)


Process finished with exit code -1
```

Could anyone please suggest solution?

Comment: Just for the record: you understand that one should only be using PowerMock(ito) in case you have to test 3rd party code which you can't modify? Because when you write your own code, and you think you need PowerMock to test it; then your problem is that you are writing hard-to-test code. Easy-to-test code doesn't need PowerMock(ito).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

PowerMock 1.6.5 already has 3.20.0-GA as dependency. From pom.xml

```
         <javaassist.version>3.20.0-GA</javaassist.version>
         <dependency>
             <groupId>org.javassist</groupId>
             <artifactId>javassist</artifactId>
             <version>${javaassist.version}</version>
             <scope>compile</scope>
         </dependency>
```

Moreover, the method was added in Javassist 3.11.

```
 /**
 * Returns true if the class has the specified annotation type.
 *
 * @param clz the annotation type.
 * @return <code>true</code> if the annotation is found, otherwise <code>false</code>.
 * @since 3.11
 */
public boolean hasAnnotation(Class clz) {
    return hasAnnotation(clz.getName());
}
```

Please, check that you don't have another version of Javassist

Since PowerMock 1.6.6 has 3.21.0-GA as dependency. [changelog](https://github.com/powermock/powermock/blob/master/changelog.txt)

> - Upgraded Javaassist dependency from 3.20.0-GA to version 3.21.0-GA

Comment: Thanks for answer, but Is there any solution for 1.6.5 PowerMock version ?

Comment: It was my fall. I missed that you need  3.20.0-GA. I don't know why, but I was thinking that you need more that 3.20.0-GA. I updated the answer. Please, check your classpath.

Comment: Actually, I don't need sertain version of javaassist, I just want to make my project be able to build. The problem is that I am using PowerMock 1.6.5 and after update target jdk to `<target-jdk>1.8</target-jdk>` I am start to facing problems shown above.

Comment: According to the issue on GitHub https://github.com/jboss-javassist/javassist/issues/115 you are thinking in a right way. You need 3.20.0-GA or upper.

Comment: I'm confused by second exception. It points that you have other version of Javassist, older than 3.11, as transitive dependency. My suggestion, check dependency tree

Comment: I've found 3.4.GA in list of libraries. The problem is that my pom file is kinda child of other pom files which I don't have access. Actually, I don't know how to resolve this. Other big joke that when I am adding wrong dependency like: javassist 3.20.0-GA without 'org' - version of javassist gets red colored and test are working

Comment: So, I've removed 3.4.GA from list of libraries and all works fine with 3.20.0.GA, thank you for help